# How to get active class name of a button, in angular (2+)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I need to get active class name of this button when
A) reactive form is submitted
B) when this button is clicked

HTML

```
 <button
  type="button"
  [className]=" condition ? 'classA' : 'classB'
  (click) = "buttonClicked($event)"
>
</button>
```

TS

```
buttonClicked(event: Event) {
  console.log(event);
  //get class active class name here i.e. classA or classB
}
```

Comment: event.target.classList

Comment: @enno.void getting error - property "classList" does not exist on type "EventTarget".

Comment: Typescript just complaints. Cast it to HTMLElement

Comment: @enno.void thanks but how to get the class value on form submit button ?

Comment: you can also pass as argument of the function the "condition" `(click)="buttonClicked($event,condition)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is *set* in the view by the condition `condition ? 'classA' : 'classB'`. Therefore, you can just know which class is applied in your TS code by writing `const classApplied = this.condition ? 'classA' : 'classB'`.